# MongoDB authenticate specific collection

Tags: mongodb

In `mongodb`,
I have user that I want him to can see few specific collection,
And don't let him find or edit the other collections at all.

for example,
lets say I have collections

```
"coll1", 
"t_coll2", 
"t_coll3", 
"coll4".
and user "t"
```

I want user `"t"` can read 2 collections:
`"t_coll2", "t_coll3"`,
and **don't** have access to `"coll1", "coll4"` for read or write.

How Can I do so?
Is that possible to give "read" role to specific collections?

Thanks

Comment: why not create another column under your collections table which let you specify accessibility code. under accessibility, you specify the levels for each column per user role. and you specify the user role as well in your user.

Comment: I don't know this solution. Can you send a link to documentation / tutorial or something?

Comment: this is just a simple relationship problem.

Comment: how can I specify user role according to column in collections table?

Comment: its really up to you on how you wanted it. this is setting of restriction or something. so for that you need to specify which role can access that certain collection. so you need to add another column in your user or have another table which sets the userID and the userrole. by then, you can specify which user can access what collection.

Comment: I still don't understand. I create new user so: db.createUser({user:"name",pwd:"pwd", roles:[{"role":"read", db:"dbname"}]}); In your way, what sould I do different?

Comment: What @bipartite is referring to is to implement an authentication and authorization on you application side (if I get it right), which is your only option, since MongoDB does not allow collection level authorization.